# SQLSyntaxErrorException in JPA One to many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two entity classes, Order class and OrderLineItems class. I am trying to create a one-many relationship between Order and OrderLineItems, i.e One Order can have multiple OrderLineItems. The code I have is given below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long orderId;
    private String orderNumber;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    private List<OrderLineItems> orderLineItems;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "order_line_items")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class OrderLineItems {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long orderLineItemsId;
    private String skuCode;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Integer quantity;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Order order;
    
}
```

The above code results in a SqlSyntaxErrorException. The relevant part of trace is given below. What am I doing wrong?

```
2022-04-16 12:39:22.643  INFO 85559 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
Hibernate: create table order (order_id bigint not null auto_increment, order_number varchar(255), primary key (order_id)) engine=InnoDB
2022-04-16 12:39:23.098  WARN 85559 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table order (order_id bigint not null auto_increment, order_number varchar(255), primary key (order_id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table order (order_id bigint not null auto_increment, order_number varchar(255), primary key (order_id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

.............
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (order_id bigint not null auto_increment, order_number varchar(255), prima' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, order is a reserved word for spring data jpa or hibernate. Try renaming your table to something else and give it another try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Table(name = "order")`: `order` is reserved word in MySQL. Change table name to something else, f.e. "orders" and it will work :)